# How to find out the color theme in the user's browser (Chrome)?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, color-scheme

Google Chrome has the ability to apply color themes. At the same time, the interface is painted. I would like part of the interface of my browser extension to inherit this color? Tell me, is it possible? Is there some way to determine the color of the Chrome interface? For sites, for extensions?

Comment: No, there's no API for that. Extensions can run an external utility that reads the screen pixel color and reports back via nativeMessaging but that's probably a huge overkill for such a task.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS media query `prefers-color-scheme` to apply different styles based on the users color scheme.

```css
fieldset {
  background-color: gainsboro;
}
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  fieldset {
    background-color: darkslategray;
  }
}
```

Check out https://web.dev/prefers-color-scheme/#the-prefers-color-scheme-media-query for more details, ways to improve loading performance, etc!

PS: The `prefers-color-scheme` media query is supported in most evergreen browsers.